# Ultimo registro de cada objeto django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo web em Python, Django e Sqlite. Tenho dois models, um para "Vendedor" e outro para "Pedidos". Preciso pegar o ultimo pedido de cada vendedor e não estou conseguindo fazer isso com o Django. Segue meus models abaixo:

```
class Vendedor(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nome', max_length=100)
    nascimento = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data Nascimento:', 
                                  help_text='Informe a data')
    endereco = models.TextField(verbose_name='Endereço:')

class Pedidos(models.Model):
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey('Vendedor', verbose_name='Vendedor:',
                                  related_name='vend', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                  null=True)

    data = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data Pedido:', help_text='Informe a data')

    LISTA_TIPO = (('Of', 'Oficina'),('Pd', 'Produto'),('Sr', 'Serviço'),)

    tipo = models.CharField(verbose_name='Tipo:', max_length=50,
                            choices=LISTA_TIPO, blank=True,
                            help_text='Informe qual o tipo', default='')
```

Cada vendedor tem vários pedidos. Preciso pegar o ultimo pedido de cada vendedor. Alguém poderia me ajudar

Comment: Depois da edição, a sua pergunta se tornou totalmente desfigurada e abrangente demais sugiro que leia com atenção [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aqui no SOpt

Comment: Ok, agora sim, tente implementar minha resposta na linha de comando, se não conseguir, acresente na pergunta ou aqui nos comentarios o que deu errado, se conseguir e continuar com problemas em outro topico então provavelmente vc deve elaborar outra pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Segui sua lógica e deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como em django existem varios contextos, vou tentar explicar com seu proprio exemplo mas em uma console django, se quiser experimentar, entre em um console python (no ambiente e diretorio do seu projeto) e execute o codigo abaixo (As explicacoes estão como comentários no próprio código):

#### Criando os objetos:

```
# Importação dos pacotes necessários
from datetime import date
from core.models import Vendedor, Pedidos

# Criando 2 vendedores
>>> Vendedor.objects.create(nome='foo', nascimento='1991-01-01', endereco='Rua que sobe e desce, 166')
>>> Vendedor.objects.create(nome='bar', nascimento='1992-02-02', endereco='Rua que sobe e desce, 777')

# Listando a queryset dos objetos vendedores
>>> Vendedor.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Vendedor: Vendedor object (1)>, <Vendedor: Vendedor object (2)>]>

# Adicionando 2 pedidos para o vendedor 1
Pedidos.objects.create(vendedor=Vendedor.objects.get(pk=1),data=date.today(), tipo='of')
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (1)>
Pedidos.objects.create(vendedor=Vendedor.objects.get(pk=1),data=date.today(), tipo='Pd')
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (2)>

# Adicionando 2 pedidos para o vendedor 2
Pedidos.objects.create(vendedor=Vendedor.objects.get(pk=2),data=date.today(), tipo='Pd')
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (3)>
Pedidos.objects.create(vendedor=Vendedor.objects.get(pk=2),data=date.today(), tipo='Sr')
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (4)>

# Listando todos os pedidos (QuerySet)
print(Pedidos.objects.all())
<QuerySet [<Pedidos: Pedidos object (1)>, <Pedidos: Pedidos object (2)>,
           <Pedidos: Pedidos object (3)>, <Pedidos: Pedidos object (4)>]>
```

#### Trabalhando com `Objects.last()`:

```
# Apresentando o ultimo pedido feito:
print(Pedidos.objects.last())
Pedidos object (4)
```

#### Trabalhando com `objects.filter()`:

```
# Apresentando o ultimo pedido do vendedor 1
Pedidos.objects.filter(vendedor=1).last()
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (2)>

# Apresentando o ultimo pedido do vendedor 2
Pedidos.objects.filter(vendedor=2).last()
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (4)>
```

### Trabalhando com `related_name`:

```
# Apresentando o ultimo pdido do vendedor 1 via related name
>>> vendedor1 = Vendedor.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> vendedor1.vend.last()
<Pedidos: Pedidos object (2)>
```

### Apresentando o último pedido de cada vendedor em um `pandas.DataFrame()`:

```
>>> data = []
>>> vendedores = Vendedor.objects.all()
>>> for v in vendedores:
        ultimo_pedido = v.vend.last()
        data.append([v.nome, ultimo_pedido.id, ultimo_pedido.data, ultimo_pedido.tipo])

>>> ultimos_pedidos = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Vendedor', 'Id Pedido','Data', 
                                                  'Tipo'])
>>> print(ultimos_pedidos)
    Vendedor  Id Pedido        Data Tipo
 0      foo           2  2019-04-18   Pd
 1      bar           4  2019-04-18   Sr
```

Comment: Primeiro muito obrigado pela ótima explicação. Estou iniciando na programação e não consegui replicar seu código em meu programa. aparece o seguinte erro:
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'semana'
Vou postar aqui meu código original para ver se pode me dizer como corrigir meu erro.

Comment: Veja que meu codigo é um exemplo em um terminal python, não é para colocar em seu programa, vc pode ate acionar um terminal reproduzir "ipsis litteris"  o meu exemplo desde que esteja no diretorio do seu projeto e no mesmo ambiente. Sugiro que retire os comentarios feitos na pergunta, pois atrapalharia alguem que tivesse o mesmo problema, faça os comentários aqui, ou podemos ir para a área de chat.

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer a ajuda. Segui a sua logica e deu certo. Já implementei no meu programa e funcionou!!